# $A: R^{n} \rightarrow R^{n}$, $A^{3}$ - projection. Eigenvalues and diag matrix in any basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, projection-matrices

Here is task:
$$A: R^{n} \rightarrow R^{n}$$
$A^{3}$ - projection.

(a) - What eigenvalues this linear operator have?

(b) - Is it true that A will have a diagonal matrix in some basis $R^{n}$?

============

I have solved (a) here it is:
$$
A^{3} - projection \rightarrow A^{6} = A^3.
$$
We can find minimal polynomial $f(A) = 0$.
$$
f(x)=x^6 - x^3 = x^3(x^3 - 1)
$$
Here we can find spectrum $A$:
$$
x^3(x^3 - 1) = x^3(x^2 + x + 1)(x - 1)
$$
And spectrum will be:
$$
λ_1=0
$$
$$
λ_2=1
$$
$$
λ_3=\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2}
$$
$$
λ_4=\frac{-1 - \sqrt{3}i}{2}
$$
Can't find next step for solve (b).

Comment: Question b) can be translated into : "is $A$ diagonalizable ?" Do you know a criterium for that involving the dimensions of the eigenspaces ?

Comment: One example of an $A$ such that $A^3$ is a projection is where $A$ is a rotation by $2\pi/3$.

Comment: For question a), more simply notice that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $A$ (hence a real number) then $\lambda^3$ is an eigenvalue of $A^3$ (hence $0$ or $1$).

Comment: @JeanMarie I know that - if $A$ diagonalizable $\rightarrow$ 
1) sum of algebraic multiplicity of all roots from characteristic polynomial equal $n$
2)Algebraic multiplicity equal $ker(A-λ_iI)$ for each $λ_i$.

Comment: In fact it is not only an "imply" but an "equivalent to".

Comment: @AnneBauval if hence 0 or 1 what is $λ_3$ and $λ_4$

Comment: @JeanMarie yes you're right, missed it.

Comment: They are not real numbers, hence not eigenvalues. They may be roots of the characteristic polynomial (like in Davis Yoschida's example above) but they have no associated eigenvector in $\Bbb R^n.$

Comment: @AnneBauval got it. Is this fact imply that A can't be diagonalizable?

Comment: The diagonalizable maps having no other eigenvalues than $0$ and $1$ are the projections.

Comment: @AnneBauval Can I use for formal proof the fact that if I found root from C (complex) the matrix can't be diagonalizable?

Comment: You mean non-real. You didn't "find" such a root yet. What you found is a *superset* of the spectrum of *every* $A$ such that $A^3$ is a projection. Some of these $A$'s are diagonalizable (those which are projections). Your idea may indeed  serve to find others which are not.

Comment: @AnneBauval if we getting roots from minimal polynomial, these roots is equals with set of spectrum. Maybe I can wrong.

Comment: $x^6-x^3$ is not necessarily the minimal polynomial. It may very well be a multiple of it. E.g. is $A$ is a non-trivial projection, its minimal polynomial is $x^2-x.$

Comment: @AnneBauval okay, if a^2 not projector we can use the fact about complex root?

Comment: You have no "fact" in your pocket. You must first choose some particular $A$ which will serve as a counterexample.